# Programando algoritmos en C, usando Zinjai. Que hice mal? No me imprime el porcentage

Tags: c++

**ENUNCIADO DEL PROBLEMA:** Un profesor conoce la cantidad de hombres y mujeres del curso de Algoritmos, deseasaber que porcentaje de hombres y que porcentaje de mujeres hay en su grupo de estudiantes.

El código es el siguiente

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int canth, cantm, total;
    
    printf("Ingrese cantidad de hombres\n");
    scanf("%d", &canth);

    printf("Ingrese cantidad de mujeres\n");
    scanf("%d", &cantm);

    total = canth + cantm;

    printf("El procentage de hombres es: ", canth / total) * 100, "%";
    printf("El porcentage de mujeres es: ", (cantm / total)) * 100, "%";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ni idea. Tú dinos qué error o problema tiene el código que incluyes, así podemos responder a una pregunta puntual

Comment: Tenes razón sorry, ya añadi el fallo. No se como imprimir el porcentage

Comment: Primero, si estás en `C++` emplea las librerías de I/O que proporciona `C++`. Las funciones `printf` y `scanf` son propias de `C` e incluidas en `stdio.h`. Lo segundo, tienes un cacao serio con los paréntesis a la hora de imprimir los resultados. Te recomiendo la estrategia de **DIVIDE Y VENCERÁS**. Obtén primero los porcentajes en una operación, y luego dicho resultado lo imprimes. Te será más fácil así hasta que adquieras más nivel programando

Comment: Muchas gracias x los consejos, te consulto, cómo cito una variable? es decir como hago que el resultado de la variable se imprima junto al mensaje? por ej: "El total de alumnos es: "total"

Answer (score 1):

- No llamas la función correctamente.

`printf` recibe como parámetros el mensaje o formato y los datos a mostrar. Cada parámetro debe indicarse en el string del primer parámetro con un signo porcentaje (%) y el tipo que se quiere imprimir mediante una letra.

Por ejemplo, si tuvieras un número entero y quieres imprimirlo en consola, lo harías así:

```
printf("Numero: %d", 123);
```

Más información [aquí](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).

- El orden de los factores sí importa. (Y se nota más en enteros).

Las instrucciones se ejecutan de arriba a abajo. Los operadores aritméticos, se asocian de izquierda a derecha.

Por ejemplo, `1 / 2 * 4` es equivalente a `(1 / 2) * 4`. Siguiendo la lógica de enteros, `1 / 2 = 0` por lo tanto `(1 / 2) * 4 = 0 * 4`. Resultando en 0.

Si en cambio, la expresión fuera `1 * 4 / 2` el resultado sería 2.

Más información sobre [precedencia y asociatividad de operadores](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

---

Corrigiendo tu código tendrías algo así:

```
printf("El procentaje de hombres es: %d%%", canth * 100 / total);
```

Nota que la forma de poder imprimir el signo de porcentaje es escribiendo 2 seguidos.

Como alternativa, puedes convertir a `float` o `double` las variables para mostrar los decimales.

```
printf("El procentaje de hombres es: %f%%", (float)(canth) / total * 100.0f);
```

---

Si realmente estás usando C++ como lo indica la etiqueta, sugiero que uses las funciones de STL, que son más fáciles de entender.

Por lo tanto, en lugar de `printf`, usarías `cout` y tendrías un código como este:

```
float porcentaje = (float)canth / total * 100.0f;
std::cout << "El procentaje de hombres es: " << porcentaje << "%";
```

No olvides de escribir `#include <iostream>` al comienzo del archivo.

Comment: Muchas gracias gente

Answer (score 1):

La función `printf` es una función *compleja* que permite dar formato a la salida a consola usando unas marcas de formato, estas marcas de formato tienen el siguiente aspecto:

> ```
> %carácter
> ```

Es decir, símbolo porcentaje (`%`) seguido de un carácter, cada uno de los caracteres que se puede poner tras el porcentaje tiene un significado diferente, en tu caso los únicos relevantes son:

- `%%` muestra el símbolo porcentaje.
- `%f` muestra números en coma flotante de precisión simple (`float`).

Así que probablemente querías hacer esto:

```
printf("El procentage de hombres es: %f%%\n", (canth * 100.f) / total);
printf("El porcentage de mujeres es: %f%%\n", (cantm * 100.f) / total);
```

Pero **NO deberías estar usando `printf`** ya que es una herramienta de [c](/questions/tagged/c) y es conocida por potenciales problemas de seguridad.

En [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) moderno deberías usar `std::format` combinado con `std::cout`:

```
std::cout
    << std::format("El procentage de hombres es: {}%\n", (canth * 100.f) / total)
    << std::format("El porcentage de mujeres es: {}%\n", (cantm * 100.f) / total);
```

O a partir de C++23 puedes usar `std::print`:

```
std::print("El procentage de hombres es: {}%\nEl porcentage de mujeres es: {}%\n",
    (canth * 100.f) / total,
    (cantm * 100.f) / total);
```

Si no puedes usar ninguna de las funcionalidades modernas de C++, simplemente usa `std::cout`:

```
std::cout
    << "El procentage de hombres es: " << ((canth * 100.f) / total) << "%\n"
    << "El porcentage de mujeres es: " << ((cantm * 100.f) / total) << "%\n";
```